# Adjust Camera PixelRect Based on Screen Resolution In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, render, orthographic

I'm creating a simple 2D game in Unity. The game has a subwindow. To create the subwindow, I added a secondary camera. Because I want the subwindow to display a small portion of my screen, I adjusted its PixelRect property.

Now, even if I scale my screen up or down, the ratio of my subwindow remains the same. However, I want my subwindow to scale up/scale down depending on the size of my screen. the thing is, I have a "border" for my subwindow. The border adjusts with the screen but I can't seem to do that with the actual camera view.

How will I make my camera using its pixelRect property adjust to the size/scale & position of its border?

Basically, i want my camera view to always fit inside the "border" regardless of the screen size.

Comment: pixelRect is not affected by any camera params. You have to change it by hands.

Comment: i know i have to manually change it. By how can I change the values when I don't know how much I should change? I just want my camera view to always follow the size of my border. The border automatically adjusts when the screen size shrinks/grow. How can I do that with my camera view? If my approach is wrong, can you tell me how may I achieve what I want?